# Java Tile Map Chunk Coordinates

Tags: java, math

I am making a 2d game in Java (this isn't relevant but someone will ask), and at the moment I have my randomly generated tilemap, I load the map into lots of smaller chunks 16x16 in size. I load it like this for better performance. My problem is getting each chunk from the world.

My issue is getting the coordinates to load that chunks blocks. For example I have a 64x64 world this would load into 16 16x16 chunks, each chunk has a world coordinate from the world to get the correct tiles for that chunk. I can draw them at the moment, but they aren't getting the corrent world coordinates.

Here is my code:

```
for(int w=0; w<this.width/Chunk.ChunkWidth; w++) {
    for(int h=0; h<this.height/Chunk.ChunkHeight; h++) {
        chunks.add(new Chunk(new Vector2f(w*Chunk.ChunkWidth*32,h*Chunk.ChunkHeight*32), w*Chunk.ChunkWidth,h*Chunk.ChunkHeight));
        System.out.println("[ Chunk Looped Coords ] " + w*Chunk.ChunkWidth + ":" + h*Chunk.ChunkHeight);
    }
}
```

The `this.width` references the world size, e.g. 64. `ChunkWidth` and `ChunkHeight` refer to the chunk height for each chunk which is the same every time. The arguments to the `Vector2f` are only there for where on the screen the chunk should be drawn which is correct, my issue the second and third argument for adding another chunk.

In my console is this:

```
[ Chunk Looped Coords ] 0:0
[ Chunk Looped Coords ] 0:16
[ Chunk Looped Coords ] 0:32
[ Chunk Looped Coords ] 0:48
[ Chunk Looped Coords ] 16:0
[ Chunk Looped Coords ] 16:16
[ Chunk Looped Coords ] 16:32
[ Chunk Looped Coords ] 16:48
[ Chunk Looped Coords ] 32:0
[ Chunk Looped Coords ] 32:16
[ Chunk Looped Coords ] 32:32
[ Chunk Looped Coords ] 32:48
[ Chunk Looped Coords ] 48:0
[ Chunk Looped Coords ] 48:16
[ Chunk Looped Coords ] 48:32
[ Chunk Looped Coords ] 48:48
```

My Game:

[image]

If you look at the top left you can see the very first x=0 column getting cut off, this is because of me trying to get the correct world position, for every chunk the chunk world position shifts over 1 tile, this also happens going down but the top column shifts 1 tile down.

What I want to happen is, in the loop it will get each quarter of the world (because of sizes I mentioned earlier) the chunks should not overlap each others tiles, at the moment they overlap 15 columns of each others tiles.

All I need is the correct maths to get the correct world position for each chunk.
If this isn't possible which other solution would be better.
Thanks.

Comment: Why are you multiplying by 32?

Comment: @Scott Hunter because each tile is 32 pixels in width and height